# string* removing of the free space

Tags: c++

I have a jar of biscuits and each biscuit is a word. I have to put and take biscuits int and out of the jar. I know how to make the putting but I have a problem with the taking.

The problem comes when the `amount == jar_volume / 2` and it doesn't let me to delete the free space.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Jar
{

private:
    string *biscuits;
    int amount;
    int jar_volume = 10;

public:

    void Take(string cookie)
    {
        if(amount == 0)
        {
            cout << "You have eaten all the cookies. Go and buy more!!!!" << endl;
            return;
        }
        else if(amount == jar_volume / 2)
        {
            string *resize = new string[jar_volume / 2];
            for(int i = this->amount; i > 0; i--)
                resize[i] = this->biscuits[i];

            this->jar_volume = this->jar_volume / 2;
            delete this->biscuits;
            this->biscuits = resize;
        }

        this->biscuits[amount--] = cookie;
    }

    int Amount()
    {
        return this->amount;
    }

    int JarVolume()
    {
        return this->jar_volume;
    }

    ~Jar()
    {
        delete this->biscuits;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Jar p;

    cout << "How many cookies do you want to take: ";
    int num_take_c;
    cin >> num_take_c;
    string take_word;

    for(int i = 0; i < num_take_c; ++i)
    {
        getline(cin, take_word);
        p.Take(take_word);
        cout << "Taken " << take_word << " cookie from the jar" << endl;
        cout << "Amount: " << p.Amount() << endl;
        cout << "Jar volume: " << p.JarVolume() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have eaten all the cookies. Go and do your homework!!!!:)

Comment: You should explain what the `Take` method is supposed to do.

Comment: `delete this->biscuits;` <-- shouldn't that be `delete [] this->biscuits;` ? But the bigger question is, why are you using `new` and `delete` in the first place. Just make `biscuits` a `vector<string>` or some such.

Comment: @Nootor Did my answer help you? Mark it as accepted if it did.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided a custom constructor for the allocation (purchase) of `biscuits` in the first place. Also, to deallocate `biscuits`, you want to use `delete []`, which will match with `new []` you're going to use for the aforementioned allocation. Last thing I see is the use of `amount` as if the minimum amount of cookies in the jar was one:

```
for(int i = this->amount; i > 0; i--) // i will not reach 0

this->biscuits[amount--] = cookie; // amount will reach 0 after the statement and won't be called next time with amount equal 0
```

You can check out `std::vector` too if you're allowed to instead of playing around with dynamic arrays.